# Is there an easier way of writing base 2 numbers in Flags?

Tags: c#, enums, flags

Is there an easier way to write the integer value for enum flags without having to remember EACH base 2 number (I tend to get lost after 4096)?

If I use, let's say, `2*2*2*2`, will that be converted to 16 at compile time or will it be executed at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public enum Foo
    {
        Bar  = 1 << 0,
        Baz  = 1 << 1,
        Quux  = 1 << 2,
        Etc  = 1 << 3
    }
```

Comment: +1 haven't used this method in C#, but for C and C++ I use this method a lot. (well, not for enums usually, but rather other long lists)

Comment: Yeah it's a handy trick. I certainly brought it with me from my C++ days too :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably use this from now on.

Comment: @OJ you have to wait 3 more minutes before he can accept it :P

Comment: How did I not know about that? :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use hex which is a little more intuitive.

```
Value1 = 0x01,
Value2 = 0x02,
Value3 = 0x04,
...
```

Or use bit shifts.

```
Value1 = 1 << 0,
Value2 = 1 << 1,
Value3 = 1 << 2,
....
```